# Ajax request is timing out too quickly

Tags: php, ajax

I am calling my php page (test.php) through ajax request, and that test.php contains list of queries under one while loop. When I call that page using ajax it terminates before its maximum execution time (I tried setting max value to max_execution_time, set_time_limit in ini/php file) and gives 500 internal server error.

When I call same test.php using url (and not through ajax request), it works properly.

Please help what might be the cause.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Are you *sure* that the internal server error is due to a timeout, or have you done something else in the request that's different? Check your HTTP log!

Comment: can I have some code please?

Comment: Yes, h200000000 internal server is due to timeout, because same thing working properly by url calling that page, i have also removed some queries from while loop to shorten it and it was working properly.

Comment: That test.php page having 500 lines of code so summaries and pasted..

Comment: Code is like 

$listOfProject = Listfromsomepostparameter($userid); 
while(each project)
{ 
$queryToGetData1; 
$queryToGetData2; 
$queryToGetData3 
$combiningalldata; 
// Added above data to one docx file. 
// returning docx file name 
}

Comment: pls provide your php error after increse set_time_limit

Answer (score 1):

you can try to increase your ajax timeout

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'phpfile.php',
    success: function (result) {                               
        //
    },
    timeout: 10000
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not using jquery ajax, its normal javascript ajax call. How to do it in that?